# Table value insertion using angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jsp, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am trying to insert table values into the row-wise.The row has two checkboxes.How will I differentiate checkboxes row-wise
HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-8"  ng-controller="checklistController" ng-init='populateChecklist(<%=request.getParameter("id")%>)'>
           <div class="table-responsive">
              <table class="table table-bordered">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Checklist Name</th>
                    <th>Not Required</th>
                    <th>Completed</th>
                    <th>Link</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                  <tbody>
                   <tr ng-repeat = "x in list">
                     <td>{{x.name}}</td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model='notRequiredCheckList'  ng-disabled="completedCheckList" ng-disabled="linkForCheckList"/></td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" ng-disabled="notRequiredCheckList" ng-model="completedCheckList" /></td>
                    <td><input type="text" ng-model="linkForCheckList" size="50" ng-disabled="notRequiredCheckList"/></td>
                   </tr>
                  </tbody>
              </table>
          </div>
             <button type"button" ng-click="savelist(list)">Send</input>
      <div>
```

Javascript:

```
app.controller("checklistController",function($scope,$http){
      $scope.populateChecklist =  function(a){
           $http.get("commonAppGet.jsp?sqlStr=select name from checklist where 
         where id="+a).then(function(resp){
                $scope.list = resp.data;
             });
}
       $scope.savelist = function(list){
         $scope.res=list;
         alert($scope.res.length);
         alert($scope.res[0].name);
         alert($scope.res[1].name);
     }
});
```

Here how I can i fetch the check box values corresponding row.I could not achieve this.How to send this data to the server for storing in the database using JSP?
Help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your code has severe security problems. You should not be passing a raw string argument into a SQL statement since it allows [SQL Injection](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp). You need to use [prepared queries](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#preparing-queries) if you don't want to get your entire database dropped.

About your question you can track your rows by index if you want to know at what row your checkboxes are inserted, for example:

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in list track by $index">
   <td>
      <input type="checkbox" data-row-index="$index">
   </td>
</tr>
```

This will make your input have an attribute that points to the current row. Note that `$index` starts at 0.
I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Thank you..Could you tell how to pass the entire thing to the saveList() function?

Comment: Do you mean pass the service result into your saveList function?
If so, you can do:
`$scope.list = resp.data;`
`saveList($scope.list);`